# Angular/JS - Dynamic content in a Google Area Chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I'm using [Google Charts Area Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart) for displaying temperatures and dates in a chart. The content I need to display is dynamic, and should be filled in on load.
I'm using Angular with Sails.js, each temperature is stored in an object *batchTemps*, and the objects are stored in an object *batchTempList* which has an array; *contents*.

I need use the batchTempList.contents to populate the Area Chart, but can't figure out a working way.

Here is an example for **static** data to generate the chart:

```
data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Time', 'Temp C°'],
      ['2017-05-31 13:44:54',  20.5],
      ['2017-05-31 13:54:54',  21.7],
      ['2017-05-31 14:04:54',  22.0],
      ['2017-05-31 14:14:54',  21.3]
    ]);
```

I want to retrieve the data from the list, and enter it like the static example above.
The *batchTemps* objects have an ID, temperature, and createdAt (date of recording).

An example I tried, but without success:

```
data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Time', 'Temp C°'],
      for (batchTemp in batchTempList.contents) {
                    ['batchTemp.createdAt', batchTemp.temperature],
                }
]);
```

JSFiddle with static solution: http://jsfiddle.net/qphnyash/

PS: In a previous version of my application, I used Sails.js with EJS, and used the following code for it to work:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Time', 'Temp C°'],
    <% _.each(brewery.temperatures, function(breweryTemp) { %>
    ['<%= breweryTemp.createdAt %>', <%= breweryTemp.temperature %>],
    <% }); %>
  ]);
```

but since I switched over to Angular, and currently use templates instead of the .ejs files, I can't use it.

Thanks in advance, 
any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that Angular and AngularJS are not the same. AngularJS refers to version 1.x, while Angular refers to version 2+. Which version are you exactly referring to?

Comment: @borislemke thanks, failed to notice that tag. I'm using Angular 1.3!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try building the array, prior to building the data table...

```
var chartData = [
  ['Time', 'Temp C°']
];

for (batchTemp in batchTempList.contents) {
  chartData.push(
    [batchTemp.createdAt, batchTemp.temperature]
  );
}

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
```

**EDIT**

to build the chart data array...

if `batchTempList.contents` is an array `[]`, and not an object `{}`,

you want to use a `forEach`...

```
batchTempList.contents.forEach(function (batchTemp) {
  chartData.push(
    [batchTemp.createdAt, batchTemp.temperature]
  );
});
```

or regular `for` loop...

```
for (var i = 0; i < batchTempList.contents.length; i++) {
  chartData.push(
    [batchTempList.contents[i].createdAt, batchTempList.contents[i].temperature]
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I will check it out and get back! :)

Comment: Works like a charm!
As per your edit, I chose to go for the forEach way.

Comment: Just to be sure, would you mind taking a look at this JSFiddle?
 https://jsfiddle.net/85rb83eL/

Comment: [here's a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/NS70qREW) with the output from `console.log(JSON.stringify(batchTempList.contents));` Once again, thanks!

Comment: Alright, no problem. I'll just edit it into the question, if that's cool?

Comment: Struggled some with the formatting; do you have access to Gists/GitHub?
[Gist here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mortea15/2465ccb5893b7a07cd43241e730466aa/raw/a85d66990b2e6355f40b1791b7a0e4321863ca92/charttest.json)

Comment: got it, i've updated [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49bbqddd/2/) with the data, which is in the expected format, code should work fine...

Comment: see the [latest updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49bbqddd/3/) if you want real dates on the x-axis, rather than strings...